# Traveling with a 5 and a half months old for a whole month; options on strollers?

Tags: travel, stroller

We will be traveling soon for a whole month in Japan with our five and a half months old daughter and we are considering buying an umbrella stroller for the trip. We have a Bugaboo Buffalo at home and we are still considering if it's best to just travel with it instead, but taking into account its bulkiness, weight and the whole lot of horrible stories of airlines destroying strollers, I am more and more doubtful.

There are a bunch of questions that still plague me about using an umbrella stroller (albeit a mid/high range price one):

• The best strollers I am seeing do not recline completely horizontal (though they recline a bit) therefore in the specifications they say minimum age is 6 months. Do you think is OK to use them with a 5 1/2 months old? Anyone have a similar experience? Or could it be problematic for the muscle development of the child?

• We will be traveling for a whole month, so is expected that our daughter will spend a fair amount of time on the umbrella stroller, even combining it with a carrier (at least she will use it for couple of hours every day). Is this type of stroller OK for this amount of use? I wouldn't do it with a cheap umbrella stroller, but hopefully a better one would be almost as comfortable and good for the baby as our regular day to day stroller.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Putting this as a comment because it's not what you asked for, but if you're going to be travelling a lot with a small child, I would really recommend carrying them in a wrap, as it keeps your hands free, takes up less space, and allows you to navigate terrain more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're going to be there for so long and you are considering buying a stroller just for the trip, why not buy one in Japan? Then leave it behind when you leave. One less thing to carry on the plane. And if you buy a cheap umbrella stroller and it fails, at least now you know where to get a new one, because you bought one your first day!

And I second Erik's idea of getting a wrap or carrier. You can use it for walking through the airport and other times a stroller would not be appropriate. And if you haven't booked a separate ticket for your child for the flights, you can strap them to you while seated and not worry about holding them.

Answer (score 0):

We like the BOB Revolution and we travel by air with it a fair amount. It folds down for stow away at gate. Its bottom folds back so you can get almost horizontal. It has a great rain cover. Its wheels roll over everything. Good for running on roads, but also good for managing all other terrain. I would definitely bring it with for a month long travel. The other benefit is that you can stow away your kids and pile all you kid stuff on too.

Answer (score 0):

We got a used Baby Jogger City Select stroller because we had two kids and it was worth every penny. Set up and take down was incredibly fast (3x faster than the Graco we had before), the wheels handled offroad very well, and the handle didn't make you sore after hours of pushing it.

The best part was, even though we paid $700 CAD for it used, we sold it two years later (after the kids were past stroller years) for $700 CAD. We put it through hell and it was still in just as good condition in terms of stability and fabric as when we bought it.